Is there a way to make the output file-name in cobol configurable (taking file-name as input from the user)?

 IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
 PROGRAM-ID. HelloProgram.
 ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
 INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
 FILE-CONTROL.
 SELECT OutputFile ASSIGN TO DYNAMIC-FILE-NAME
                 ORGANIZATION IS SEQUENTIAL.
       
 DATA DIVISION.
 FILE SECTION.
 FD OutputFile.
 01 OutputRecord.
    05  Field1   PIC X(6).
    05  Field2   PIC X(6).
    05  Field3   PIC XX.
           
       
    WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    01 Name PIC X(50).
    01 DYNAMIC-FILE-NAME PIC X(20).
       
 PROCEDURE DIVISION.
 AcceptFileName.
     DISPLAY "Enter output file name:" WITH NO ADVANCING
     ACCEPT DYNAMIC-FILE-NAME.
                 
 AcceptName.
     DISPLAY "Enter your name: " WITH NO ADVANCING.
     ACCEPT Name.
           

 WriteToFile.
     OPEN OUTPUT OutputFile.
     MOVE "Hello " TO Field1 OF OutputRecord.
     MOVE Name TO Field2 OF OutputRecord.
     MOVE "!" to Field3 OF OutputRecord.
     WRITE OutputRecord.
     CLOSE OutputFile.

 ReadFromFile.
     OPEN INPUT OutputFile.
     READ OutputFile.
     DISPLAY "Record read: " OutputRecord.
     CLOSE OutputFile.

 MAIN-LOGIC SECTION.
     AcceptFileName.
     AcceptName.
     WriteToFile.
     ReadFromFile.
     STOP RUN.

I want the Output file's name to configurable, (NOT HARDCODED IN THE CODE and acceptable from the user) The compiler I am using is not allowing me to use the keyword INTO, DYNAMIC . Also I want the program to read the length of the name and decide the space by itself but my compiler is not allowing EOF keyword as well.

The NetCOBOL user guide specifies that you can use the dynamic name resolution, just not with coding the DYNAMIC keyword.
 FILE-CONTROL.
   SELECT  file-1
       ASSIGN TO data-name-1.
 ...
   01 data-name-1  PIC X(256).
 ...
   ACCEPT data-name-1.
   OPEN file-1.

This approach works with most (or even all?) COBOL environments on PC.
Some environments do space-delimit the name, if this is done then you can often get around that by using quotes:
   IF NOT data-name-1 (1:1) = SPACE OR QUOTE
      MOVE data-name-1 TO tmp-name
      STRING QUOTE FUNCTION-TRIM (tmp-name) QUOTE
             INTO data-name-1.

